# Avoiding multiple calls in observable pipeline

Tags: system.reactive, akavache

I am trying to create a `GetAndFetch` method that would first return data from the cache, then fetch and return data from a webservice, and finally update the cache.

Such a function exists in `akavache` already, however, the data that is retrieved or stored by it is like a blob. i.e if I am interested in a `rss` feed I could only work at the level of whole feed and not individual items. I am interested in creating a version that returns the items as `IObservable<Item>`. This has the advantage that new `Item`s can be displayed as soon they are returned by `service` and not wait for all the `Items`s.

```cs
public IObservable<Item> GetAndFetch(IBlobCache cache, string feedUrl)
{
    // The basic idea is to first get the cached objects
    IObservable<HashSet<Item>> cacheBlobObject = cache.GetObject<HashSet<Item>>(feedUrl);

    // Then call the service   
    IObservable<Item> fetchObs = service.GetItems(feedUrl);

    // Consolidate the cache & the retrieved data and then update cache
    IObservable<Item> updateObs = fetchObs
                                      .ToArray()
                                      .MyFilter() // filter out duplicates between retried data and cache
                                      .SelectMany(arg =>
                                      {
                                          return cache.InsertObject(feedUrl, arg)
                                          .SelectMany(__ => Observable.Empty<Item>());
                                      });

    // Then make sure cache retrieval, fetching and update is done in order
    return cacheBlobObject.SelectMany(x => x.ToObservable())
                .Concat(fetchObs)
                .Concat(upadteObs);
}
```

The issue with my approach is that `Concat(upadteObs)` resubscribes to the `fetchObs` and ends up calling the `service.GetItems(feedUrl)` again which is wasteful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sound like you need the `.Publish(share => { ... })` overload.

Try this:

```
public IObservable<Item> GetAndFetch(IBlobCache cache, string feedUrl)
{
    // The basic idea is to first get the cached objects
    IObservable<HashSet<Item>> cacheBlobObject = cache.GetObject<HashSet<Item>>(feedUrl);

    return
        service
            .GetItems(feedUrl)
            .Publish(fetchObs =>
            {
                // Consolidate the cache & the retrieved data and then update cache
                IObservable<Item> updateObs =
                    fetchObs
                        .ToArray()
                        .MyFilter() // filter out duplicates between retried data and cache
                        .SelectMany(arg =>
                            cache
                                .InsertObject(feedUrl, arg)
                                .SelectMany(__ => Observable.Empty<Item>()));

                // Then make sure cache retrieval, fetching and update is done in order
                return
                    cacheBlobObject
                        .SelectMany(x => x.ToObservable())
                        .Concat(fetchObs)
                        .Concat(updateObs);
            });
}
```

I'm concerned about the `Concat` calls - they might need to be `Merge`.

Also, it seems like your call to `service.GetItems` is getting all items anyway - how is it avoiding the items already in the cache?

---

An alternative implementation based on the comments:

```
public IObservable<Item> GetAndFetch(IBlobCache cache, string feedUrl)
{
    return
    (
        from hs in cache.GetObject<HashSet<Item>>(feedUrl)
        let ids = new HashSet<string>(hs.Select(x => x.Id))
        select
            hs
                .ToObservable()
                .Merge(
                    service
                        .GetItems(feedUrl)
                        .Where(x => !ids.Contains(x.Id))
                        .Do(x => cache.InsertObject(feedUrl, new [] { x })))
    ).Merge();
}
```

Comment: I tried `Merge` but that did not work and I am not sure about the reasons. `service.GetItems` may indeed get the same items that are already in the cache. I am relying on the layer above (`dynamic data`) to filter out the duplicates. Let me try your solution and get back to you.

Comment: @resp78 - I assume then that if `service.GetItems` returns items already in the cache then you are using the cache to always have the same instance of each item and it's not about reducing the number of items that you fetch?

Comment: Not really, I had to keep the code brief, there are various places where policy can be applied to expire the items in the cache, like filtering out at the time of return (so layers above don't see them) and then updating the cache. `MyFilter()` could do little more than suggested by my comments.

Comment: @resp78 - What's the point of the cache then if you're fetching all values anyway and you're not worried about keeping references the same?

Comment: First, quick response to the user, while new data is fetched. Second, if the network is down the cache is going to serve them in offline mode.

Comment: @resp78 - Do each `Item` instance have a key or id property?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to add one.

Comment: @resp78 - I've added an alternative implementation.

Comment: The first solution seems to be working if I change `.Concat(updateObs);` to `Merge`.

Comment: @resp78 - Does the second solution work? It avoids the calls to `.ToArray()` which can appear to kill performance.